# NavigationBar Color Refresh during switching the tabview swiftui

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, navigationbar, tabview

I tried to change the navigationBar color into blue, but the navigationbar color shows a short refresh after switching between the tabview (blue - short white (refresh) - blue). Fortunately it works well for a single view.

Please could anyone give me a help for the refresh issue?
[Example blue navigatiebar, during tab switch it will refresh (white) and turn blue again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVPVL.png)